# Python: Query to InfluxDB slows down after a couple of sequential calls

Tags: python, performance, influxdb

I am running a Influx-DB Instance in a docker container on a Macbook with 8 GB RAM (so I am a bit at the limit). I am writing a Python program performing queries to the database. As fetching large chunks of data fails with a timeout, I am doing sequential calls where I fetch data belonging to one hour of data taking. This is my code of sequentially calling the database:

```
for day in range(15,25,1):
        for hour in range(0,24, 1):
            lowerDate = '2019-03-' + f'{day:02}'
            lowerHour = f'{hour:02}' + ':00:00'
            upperDate = lowerDate
            upperHour = f'{hour:02}' + ':59:59'
            rawDataSet: pd.DataFrame = influxDataReader.getRawDataByAcqTimeFrame(lowerDate=lowerDate,
                                                                           lowerTime=lowerHour,
                                                                           upperDate=upperDate,
                                                                           upperTime=upperHour)

            if rawDataSet is not None and rawDataSet.size > 0:
                resultRawData = resultRawData.append(rawDataSet)
                print('Got data for ' + lowerDate + 'T' + lowerHour + '. resultRawData.size = ' +
                      str(resultRawData.size))
            else:
                print('No data: ' + lowerDate + 'T' + lowerHour + '.')

            time.sleep(1.0)
```

Method getRawDatabyTimeFrame:

```
def getRawDataByAcqTimeFrame(self, lowerDate: str, lowerTime: str, upperDate: str, upperTime: str):
    queryStatement = """SELECT rawdata,
     sequenceStartStamp, 
     timestampCycle
     from YRT1DT1F_rawdata 
     WHERE time >= '""" + \
                     lowerDate + 'T' + lowerTime + '.0Z' + """' AND time <= '""" + \
                     upperDate + 'T' + upperTime + '.0Z' + """'"""

    result: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(self._influxConnector.executeQueryStatement(queryStatement).get_points())
        if dropDuplicateRows:
            result = result.drop_duplicates()
        return result
```

And finally the "executeQuery()" method:

```
def executeQuery(self, selectStatement: str, chunked: bool = False, chunksize: int = 10000) -> influxdb.resultset.ResultSet:
    if self._influxClient is None:
        print('Initializing DB...')
        self.initDbClient()

    try:
        queryResult: influxdb.resultset.ResultSet = self._influxClient.query(selectStatement,
                                                                             chunked=chunked,
                                                                             chunk_size=chunksize)
    except Exception as err:
        print('Error while executing DB statement: ' + selectStatement + '. Error message: ' + str(err))
    finally:
        self._influxClient.close()

    try:
        queryResult
    except Exception as err:
        print('queryResult was not assigned.')
        raise err
    else:
        return queryResult
```

This code returns data for the first three calls (2019-03-15T00:00:00.0Z - 2019-03-15T02:59:59.0Z) as expected. There is no data available in the DB between 2019-03-15T03:00:00 and 2019-03-22T23:59:59 so the code returns an empty `rawDataSet` and issues message "No data: ..." as well as expected.

The problem is that the execution of this code is expectedly fast up to 2019-03-17T23:00:00 (calls returning empty `rawDataSet` are executed every ~second). Then, starting with 2019-03-18T:00:00:00, the execution slows down dramatically: each "empty" call suddenly take 30 seconds or even a minute.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I guess no one of us can magically add resources to your dev environment. What I tend to do is to fire up a cloud instance based on a template which has docker installed and run the stuff (in your case, an influxdb) there. Combine with [ssh tunnels](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example), it costs cents and saves a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

how take long when you run this query on CLI mode?